# Can you convert a .tflite model file to .coreml - or back to a Tensorflow .pb file or keras h5 file?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, coreml, tensorflow-lite

General question: is there tooling to convert *from* tflite format to any other format?

I'm trying to convert a keras model to a CoreML model, but I can't because the model uses a layer type unsupported by CoreML (Gaussian Noise). Converting the keras .h5 model to a .tflite is simple, removes the offending layer (which is only used in training anyway), and performs some other optimisations. But it doesn't seem possible to convert out of the resultant tflite to any other format. Coremltools doesn't support tflite. I thought I could probably load the model from tflite into a tensorflow session, save a .pb from there, and convert that to coreml using coremltools, but I can't see a way to load the tflite model into a tensorflow session. I saw the documentation linked to in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664279/converting-tflite-to-pb), but that seems to use the tflite interpreter to read the tflite model, rather than a "true" Tensorflow session.

Comment: You can remove the offending layer from the Keras model before converting to Core ML. You can also replace it with an empty custom layer in Core ML (by telling the Keras converter to allow custom layers) and remove that afterwards from the Core ML model.