# Further optimize a tflite model

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

There are tools available everywhere to take keras models(.pb) as input, optimize it and save it as tflite. (viz., toco and tflite convert)
What I am interested however is to import existing tflite model and optimize it for size.

More specifically, I want [this](https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/tflite/coco_ssd_mobilenet_v1_1.0_quant_2018_06_29.zip) object detection model to about 1 MB size (obviously with accuracy tradeoffs)

This is a beautiful tool to visualize a model: https://lutzroeder.github.io/netron/

I went through a similar thread but it seems outdated:
[Converting .tflite to .pb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664279/converting-tflite-to-pb)

There must be a way to achieve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no officially supported way of further optimizing an already converted TFLite model, unfortunately. Taking a TensorFlow model and converting it to a TFLite model, optionally applying optimization techniques is the only supported path.

That being said, for your specific model, I believe this is the source TensorFlow model.
https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28.tar.gz

And then, you could use the following guide to convert it to TFLite.
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_mobile_tensorflowlite.md