# is it possible to convert tflite to tf model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I converted the TF model, which was a float, into a Tflite model, which was an integer, so that I could make inferences on the Edge device. Tflite is a lightweight model, and it is simple to deploy. Tflite, on the other hand, has a few functions and input allocations that are different from those of TF. Consequently, I would like to revert to using TF. If there is anyone who has any insight into this matter. Leave your thoughts in the comments.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because there are some information lost during the conversion (e.g. due to several optimization steps, etc.), there's no defined way to convert this back. In case you want to revert flatbuffer (.tflite) back to the fozen graph (.pb), you can refer to this [Converting .tflite to .pb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664279/converting-tflite-to-pb).